Full Mathematical Proof of the Bootstrap Method
I am trying to derive a mathematical proof for the bootstrap method in statistics. I tried to state the bootstrap method in my own language:
The sampling distribution of an estimator can be approximated by the distribution of that estimator computed from resamples of the observed data.
Now I am wondering how to prove this. Everywhere, I just read that the proof of this is obvious using Law of Large Numbers and Central Limit Theorem - but it never seemed obvious to me. I found an excellent link about this here https://www.stat.cmu.edu/%7Elarry/=sml/Boot.pdf which is quite good, but I still have questions on how this proof works. I am trying to tackle this from the start.

First, I tried to define all the definitions I will need for this proof:

Let $X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n$ be i.i.d. random variables with distribution $F$.

Let $\theta = T(F) $ be the parameter of interest.

Let $ \hat{\theta} = t(X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n)$  be an estimator of $\theta$

Let $F_n$  be the empirical distribution function (EDF) of the sample

Let $F_n(x) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n I(X_i \leq x)$

Let $ X_1^*, X_2^*, \ldots, X_n^*$ be a bootstrap sample drawn from  F_n$

Let $\hat{\theta}^* = t(X_1^*, X_2^*, \ldots, X_n^*)$ be the bootstrap estimator

Let $ H_n(x)$ be the bootstrap distribution function

Let $ G_n(x)$ be the true sampling distribution function

Let $ G(x)$ be the limiting distribution function



Now, based on all these definitions, we need to define the functions of interest needed for this proof:
$$ H_n(x) = P(\sqrt{n}(\hat{\theta}^* - \hat{\theta}) \leq x | X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n)
$$
$$
G_n(x) = P(\sqrt{n}(\hat{\theta} - \theta) \leq x)
$$
From here, it seems obvious that to prove the bootstrap theorem, we need to prove that difference between the the true sampling distribution and the bootstrap sampling distribution converges to $0$ as the number of samples $n$ increases:
$$
\sup_x |H_n(x) - G_n(x)| \xrightarrow{P} 0 \text{ as } n \rightarrow \infty
$$
The supremum gives us the largest possible difference between $H_n(x)$ and $G_n(x)$ over all $x$. If this largest difference converges to zero, then all smaller differences must also converge to zero.

The lecture notes suggest using the Triangle Inequality. In general, the triangle inequality is:
$$ |a + b| \leq |a| + |b| $$
For functions, I should be able to write:
$$ |f(x) - h(x)| \leq |f(x) - g(x)| + |g(x) - h(x)| $$
For the bootstrap theorem, we should be able to adapt this:

$ H_n(x)$ is the bootstrap distribution function
$ G_n(x)$ is the sampling distribution function
$ G(x)$ is the limiting distribution function

We want to bound the difference between $H_n(x)$ and $G_n(x)$:
$$ |H_n(x) - G_n(x)| $$
I used the classic trick of introducing $G(x)$ by adding and subtracting it:
$$ |H_n(x) - G_n(x)| = |(H_n(x) - G(x)) + (G(x) - G_n(x))| $$
Now, applying the triangle inequality:
$$ |(H_n(x) - G(x)) + (G(x) - G_n(x))| \leq |H_n(x) - G(x)| + |G(x) - G_n(x)| $$
I took the supremum of both sides:
$$ \sup_x |H_n(x) - G_n(x)| \leq \sup_x |H_n(x) - G(x)| + \sup_x |G(x) - G_n(x)| $$
This is now made of the two parts: The difference between $H_n(x)$ and the limiting distribution $G(x)$ and the difference between $G(x)$ and $G_n(x)$. Ideally, this should help us prove the convergence of $H_n(x)$ to $G_n(x)$ by showing that both of these differences converge to zero as $n$ approaches infinity.
Now, we need to analyze different parts of this inequality.

To analyze the first part of the inequality, I think we need to use the Glivenko-Cantelli theorem. The Glivenko-Cantelli theorem states that the empirical distribution function converges uniformly to the true distribution function as the sample size increases ($F_n(x)$ is the empirical distribution function and $F(x)$ is the true cumulative distribution ):
$$ \sup_x |F_n(x) - F(x)| \xrightarrow{a.s.} 0 \text{ as } n \rightarrow \infty $$
From the triangle inequality above:
$$ \sup_x |H_n(x) - G_n(x)| \leq \sup_x |H_n(x) - G(x)| + \sup_x |G(x) - G_n(x)| $$
Within the triangle inequality , $H_n(x) - G(x)$ looks very similar to $F_n(x) - F(x)$ .
Thus, using Glivenko-Cantelli theorem:
$$ \sup_x |H_n(x) - G(x)| \xrightarrow{P} 0 $$

Revisiting the triangle inequality from above, we need to show $\sup_x |G(x) - G_n(x)| \xrightarrow{P} 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.
I think this can be done using Central Limit Theorem. Define:
$$ G_n(x) = P(\sqrt{n}(\hat{\theta} - \theta) \leq x) $$
$$ G(x) = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} G_n(x) $$
If we apply the Central Limit Theorem to $\hat{\theta}$ (here, $\sigma^2$ is the asymptotic variance of $\hat{\theta}$):
$$ \sqrt{n}(\hat{\theta} - \theta) \xrightarrow{d} N(0, \sigma^2) \text{ as } n \rightarrow \infty $$
This means that $G(x)$ is the cumulative distribution function (CDF) of $N(0, \sigma^2)$ (where $\Phi$ is the standard normal CDF):
$$ G(x) = \Phi(\frac{x}{\sigma}) $$
In general, for finite $n$, $G_n(x)$ is the CDF of $\sqrt{n}(\hat{\theta} - \theta)$:
$$ G_n(x) = P(\sqrt{n}(\hat{\theta} - \theta) \leq x) $$
The lecture notes suggest that difference between $G_n(x)$ and $G(x)$ can be bounded using the Berry-Esseen theorem:
$$ \sup_x |G_n(x) - G(x)| \leq \frac{C \rho}{\sigma^3 \sqrt{n}} $$
Where $C$ is a constant, $\rho = E[|\sqrt{n}(\hat{\theta} - \theta)|^3]$, and $\sigma^2 = Var(\sqrt{n}(\hat{\theta} - \theta))$.
As $n \rightarrow \infty$, the right-hand side of the inequality converges to 0:
$$ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{C \rho}{\sigma^3 \sqrt{n}} = 0 $$
Therefore:
$$ \sup_x |G_n(x) - G(x)| \xrightarrow{P} 0 \text{ as } n \rightarrow \infty $$

I am not fully confident if I have correctly interpreted and applied all theorems, but I think that this analysis justifies the original claim of the Bootstrap Theorem. Can someone please help me confirm if I have done this correctly?
